# How add AngularJS expression in element.setAttribute

Tags: angularjs

I create button in service and i need add expression to element? How to do it?
This what I have:

```js
var element = document.createElement('div');
...
element.setAttribute('ng-attr-title', "{{isShowRegionName?'Show region name':'Hide region name'}}");
...
```

Comment: _create button in service_ ... AngularJS service? ... _i need add expression to element_ ... what kind of expression? like `ng-attr-title` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [$compile service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) (look for `Usage` near the bottom of the documentation) for this purpose.

Like so:

`var element = $compile('<div ng-attr-title="{{isShowRegionName?\'Show region name\':\'Hide region name\'}}"></div>')(scope);`

where `scope` is the scope that should be bound to, the one that contains `isShowRegionName`.